# Sum of booking per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am trying to get the `sum` of the overtime per user **NOT** per booking which is what it is doing now: [Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWTgu.png)

**Controller**

```
def index
    @users = User.all
    @hospital_bookings = HospitalBooking.scoped
  end
end
```

**Index.html.erb**

```
<%@users.each do |user|%>
  <% user.hospital_bookings.each do |hospital_booking| %>
   {
      name:'<%= hospital_booking.user.try(:name)%>',
      data:[<%= @hospital_bookings.where(:user_id => 
     hospital_booking.user.id).all.sum(&:overtime)%>]
    },
  <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

**Models**

```
#User.rb
has_many :hospital_bookings

#hospital_booking
belongs_to :user
```

**Schema.rb**

```
create_table "hospital_bookings", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "booking_reference"
    t.datetime "created_at",                                       :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                                       :null => false
    t.integer  "hospital_id"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.date     "day"
    t.string   "shift_type"
    t.decimal  "overtime",          :precision => 10, :scale => 0
  end
```

I have tried the following and these both do not seem to work.

```
**Attempt1**
<%= @hospital_bookings.where(:user_id => user.id, :hospital_booking =>
 hospital_id ).all.sum(&:overtime)%>

**Attempt2**
<%= HospitalBooking.where(user_id: user.id, 
 hospital_id: hospital.id).sum(:overtime) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you seem to ask for the sum of all overtimes of a given user `user`

```
user.hospital_bookings.sum(:overtime)
```

and limited to a given hospital

```
user.hospital_bookings.where(:hospital_id => hospital.id).sum(:overtime)
```

(which should be identical to your *Attempt2* however)

*edit after comment*:
your second iteration created  the duplicates. if you iterate only over the users and sum their overtime, you should get your desired output.

```
<% @users.each do |user|%>
   {
      name:'<%= user.name %>',
      data:[<%= user.hospital_bookings.sum(&:overtime)%>]
    },
 <% end %>
```

Comment: I did try `user.hospital_bookings.sum(:overtime)` this before and this gave me the same output as I posted - http://i.imgur.com/dhGgzGz.png. What I am trying to do is get my chart looking like this http://jsfiddle.net/Lgd8d/. Additionally I also tried `user.hospital_bookings.where(:hospital_id => hospital.id).sum(:overtime)` but this resulted in a `undefined local variable or method 'hospital'`

Comment: @user532339, maybe I am missing something, the fiddle-example is very similar to your image, unless you mean that the values are sorted? regarding your error, you need to have hospital defined (like in your _Attempt2_)

Comment: The two images are completely different the first one you notice that the names are repeating i.e. "Chris" appears twice. That is because Chris is booked for two different hospitals but has done `overtime` at both. So instead of having his name appear twice, I am trying to have it so it takes the user and all their bookings and sums their overtime. You mentioned that "I need to have hospital defined like my 2nd attempt". Do you mean setting it up like the following `<%= User.HospitalBooking.where(:hospital_id => hospital.id).sum(:overtime) %>`

Comment: with 'have hospital defined' I mean that you define the variable hospital (like the _error-message_ says). in erb that would be `<% hospital = Hospital.find(7) %>`, for example.